# FreeLibrary() Access Violation

Tags: c++, dll

Follwing Code should scan a directory with .dll for Plugin containers. If it encounters a non-Container .dll, it crashes at the given location with an Access Violation Exception
(Execution at 0x00000000). I am pretty sure that this is not a overflow error or similar because it is freed right after being loaded. I can guarantee there is not a single call of the dll's function. Only the GetProcAddress trying to figure out my entry point to the Plugin discovery.

What else can go wrong here? Could it be that im freeing a module that one of my plugin-dll's is internally linking to? If so, how could I detect this is the case, and opt for not calling FreeLibrary in this case?

```
string filePathStr (path);
string fileSearchKey = filePathStr + "\\*.dll";
WIN32_FIND_DATAA fd;
HMODULE hmod;
bool bFirstRun = true;
bool bFinishedRun = false;
HANDLE h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
printf("\r\n");
while (!bFinishedRun)
{
    if (bFirstRun)
    {
        h = FindFirstFileA(fileSearchKey.c_str(), &fd); 
        bFirstRun = false;
    } else
    {
        if (FindNextFileA(h, &fd) == FALSE) bFinishedRun = true;
    }

    if (!SetDllDirectoryA(filePathStr.c_str())) break;  

    hmod = LoadLibraryA(fd.cFileName);
    if (!hmod) continue;

    rpiRegisterPluginsCall prpiRegisterPlugins = reinterpret_cast<rpiRegisterPluginsCall>(GetProcAddress(hmod, "_rpiRegisterPlugins@4"));
    if (prpiRegisterPlugins == NULL)
    {
        FreeLibrary(hmod); // Access violation
        continue;
    }
    if (prpiRegisterPlugins(this) != 0)
    {
        FreeLibrary(hmod);
        continue;
    }

    m_loaded.push_back((unsigned long long)hmod);

}
```

Edit:

Apparently there is only one offending .dll in many non-containers (deleted that one and it works). So I am opting for the explanation that something goes wrong in dllmain.

Comment: It seems to me after the last iteration of the loop you should explicitly break out (or continue) after bFinishedRun = true to avoid processing the last file twice but that doesn't explain the problem you are experiencing afaik.

Comment: The dlls are reference counted, so free'ing a library that something else has loaded as well should not be a problem, it would only decrement the reference count. .dlls run code when they're loaded/unloaded though, through their DllMain() function.

Comment: FreeLibrary() has side-effects, it runs code in the DLL you loaded.  Clean-up code written in the DllMain() function.  Such code can easily fall over if it makes too many assumptions, like the DLL being properly initialized.  High odds that this didn't happen of course.  The exception you got is a simple null pointer dereference.  Crummy code has only one good fix if you can't get a hold of the programmer that wrote it, delete the DLL.